# Problems with longer getline cin inputs

Tags: c++, input, getline, cin

I'm writing a C++ program which asks the user to enter a word or sentence, goes through the word/sentence, replaces all instances of 'a' or 'A' with 'aoa' or 'AoA' and then outputs the result. However, I'm having issues if I attempt to type in a longer sentence. For example, if I type "why wont the program behave", the program outputs strange letters instead of the expected result.
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
string mening, temp; //The mening string is the word/sentence the user will input.
int play = 1, add;

while (play == 1) {
cout<<"Type in the sentence: ";

getline(cin, mening); //The input is saved in the string variable mening.

unsigned long y = mening.size(); //Grabs the amount of characters in input; this number is saved in the unsigned long variable y.
add = 0; //Makes sure the int variable add is reset to 0 if the loop restarts.

for (int k = 0, n = 1;n<=y;k++, n++) {
    if (mening[k] == 'a' || mening[k] == 'A') {
        k++;


        for (int i = k, m = 1;m<=y - n;i++, m++) {
            temp[i] = mening[i];
        } //The characters after the one that has been checked are stored in temp array indexes, if the character that has been checked is an a or A.

        for (int i = k, m = 1, j = k + 2;m<=y - n;i++, m++, j++) {
            mening[j] = temp[i];
        } //The characters after the one that has been checked move two steps to the right, to allow the two extra letters.

        mening[k] = 'o';
        mening[k + 1] = mening[k - 1];

        k++;

        add = add + 2; //The int variable add is increased by 2 during each aoa/AoA to avoid strange characters being outputted at the very end.

    }
    else { }

}

for (int k = 0;k<=y + add - 1;k++) {
    cout<<mening[k];
}

cout<<endl<<"Do you want to do it again? (yes/no): ";

getline(cin, mening);

    cin.clear();
    cout << flush;
    cout.flush();
    cout.clear();

if (mening == "Yes" || mening == "yes" || mening == "YES") {

}
else {
    play = 2;
}
}


cout<<endl<<"The program will now close.";

return 0;
}
```

What could be causing the problem?

Comment: I would sit down and rethink your algorithm.  It's complex for the idea.  You need to just iterate the letters once and build a new string.

Comment: I bet you are writting off the end of the string. Use the built-in string member functions to manipulate its content. (like insert or erase).

Comment: PS. code formatting counts a lot. Please make it easy to read.

Comment: Loki: Regarding code formatting, I'd like to know what you are referring to specifically. This was my first post at Stack Overflow by the way.

Answer (score 1):

One immediate problem is that you're indexing from `[1,n]`,
whereas C++ (`std::string`, `std::vector`, but also C style
arrays) uses `[0,n)`.  This means that you'll access beyond the
end of the string.  And you're storing characters into `temp`
with `temp[x]`, although the size of `temp` is always 0.  Both
of these are undefined behavior, which could have any effect
(including crashing the program).

You should use the debugging modes of the standard library when
developing code.  In Visual Studios, I think that this is the
default; with g++, you need to add `-D_GLIBCXX_CONCEPT_CHECKS
-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC` to your command
line.

The simplest way of handling this is to copy into a new string,
making the changes as you go:

```
std::string results;
for ( auto current = mening.cbegin(); current != mening.cend(); ++ current ) {
    switch ( *current ) {
    case 'a':
        results += "aoa";
        break;

    case 'A':
        results += "AoA";
        break;

    default:
        results += *current;
        break;
    }
}
```

If you do want to do the replacement in place, it gets tricky.
When you insert more text than you started with, iterators are
invalidated.  So you'd need something like:

```
static std::string const Ao( "Ao" );
static std::string const ao( "ao" );
for ( auto current = mening.begin(); current != mening.end(); ++ current ) {
    switch ( *current ) {
    case 'a':
        current = mening.insert( current, ao.begin(), ao.end() ) + 2;
        break;

    case 'A':
        current = mening.insert( current, Ao.begin(), Ao.end() ) + 2;
        break;
    }
}
```

Personally, I'd favor copying into a new string.

Comment: @LokiAstari I suggest you look at the code.  I use the iterator returned by `insert` after the `insert`.  (On the other hand, I didn't get the return value right.  I'll correct that.)

Comment: James, your comments are great. I didn't know that you must have a size for a string before you can assign array values for it, nor that you must assign from 0, because you don't have to declare arrays when using string. I'm sorry if this was a very stupid question.

Comment: @MånsNilsson Nothing stupid about it.  It seems like a lot of people make the same mistake, when starting.  But that's why we use things like `+=` (or `push_back` on a vector).  These functions automatically grow the string.

Comment: I've settled to your first suggestion, James. Why go through all the pain of rearranging with array numbers etc when you might just as well copy each letter into a new string? I didn't know that you could add to a string. Now I only have 60 rows of code, and it works wonderfully! Well, it's clear that I am still a beginner at programming. But hopefully I will take these things into account during my next project. :)

Comment: @MånsNilsson I normally use variants on the first solution myself.  When I tried the second, I was somewhat surprised that it resulted in less lines of code, but I still find the first cleaner and easier to understand and to modify.  (The second confused Loki Astari, who's a regular here, and knows C++ well.  The rules for iterators into a container which is being mutated _are_ somewhat complex.)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should use the standard function `std::string::insert` to insert the characters `'oA'` or `'oa'`. It will make your code much simpler to handle and debug.

Or you can do it simply like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
string mening, temp; //The mening string is the word/sentence the user will input.
int play = 1, add;

while (play == 1) {
cout<<"Type in the sentence: ";

getline(cin, mening); //The input is saved in the string variable mening.

unsigned long y = mening.size(); //Grabs the amount of characters in input; this number is saved in the unsigned long variable y.
add = 0; //Makes sure the int variable add is reset to 0 if the loop restarts.

for (int n = 0; n<y; n++ ) {
    cout << mening[n];
    if (mening[n] == 'a' || mening[n] == 'A') 
        cout << "o" << mening[n];
}

cout<<endl<<"Do you want to do it again? (yes/no): ";

getline(cin, mening);

    cin.clear();
    cout << flush;
    cout.flush();
    cout.clear();

if (mening == "Yes" || mening == "yes" || mening == "YES") {

}
else {
    play = 2;
}
}


cout<<endl<<"The program will now close.";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think there is no need to store the new sentence. Just output it when processing.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


std::string ReplaceA(std::string s) {
    std::string temp = "";
    for (unsigned int k = 0; k < s.size(); k++) {
        if (s[k] == 'a' || s[k] == 'A') {
            temp = temp + s[k];
            temp = temp + "o";
            temp = temp + s[k];
            }
            else { 
                temp = temp + s[k];
            }

        }
    return temp;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::string mening; //The mening string is the word/sentence the user will input.
    int play = 1;

    while (play == 1) {
        std::cout<<"Type in the sentence: ";

        getline(std::cin, mening); //The input is saved in the string variable mening.

        std::cout << ReplaceA(mening) << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Do you want to do it again? (yes/no): ";

        std::cin >> mening;
        if( std::cin.fail() || ( mening != "yes" && mening != "no" ) ) {
            std::cout << "Bad Input\nDo you want to do it again? (yes/no): ";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore('256','\n');
            std::cin >> mening;
        }else{
            if(mening == "no") break;
        }
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore('256','\n');

    }


    std::cout << "The program will now close.";

    return 0;
}
```

More organized, with a function that handles the conversion that returns a string.

You can also try this function, both work, one seems to be a little bit prettier.

```
std::string ReplaceA(std::string s) {
    std::string temp = "";
    for(std::string::iterator k = s.begin(); k != s.end(); k++) {
        switch(*k) {
        case 'a': temp += "aoa"; break;
        case 'A': temp += "AoA"; break;
        default: temp += *k; break;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Factoring the transformations out into a separate function is a good idea.  But just a suggestion: use `+=` on the return value, rather than the more complicated `temp = temp + ...`.

Comment: Yeah, was tracking down a bug. `temp += s[k] + "o" + s[k];` gave me unexpected output so I just wrote it out long to fix it.  Probably the `s[k]+"o"+s[k]` is the problem

Comment: To tell the truth, I'd just use a switch, and treat `'a'` and `'A'` in separate cases, so I could write `temp += "aoa";` or `temp += "AoA";`.  Personally, that seems a bit simpler.  To me, anyway.  (Once you've stopped trying to do the changes in place, and have factored them out into a separate function, like you've done, the details really aren't that important.)

Answer (score 0):

actually there is a trailing character '\n' remaining from last cin>>,so getline take this '\n' character and gets terminated; ignore the content of buffer before getline...

cin.ignore();
getling(cin, string_name)